# single char from socket, one at a time

Tags: c, sockets, char

I'm working on a small telnetish game in C with text based gui.
I need to get a single char from a socket without '\n' needed so i can get control over keys.

I have something like

```
16     char buffer[256];
17     bzero(buffer,256);
18     n = read(sock,buffer,255);
```

but `read()` accepts only `char *`.

`recv()` is better but you still need to pass '\n' to get it.

I found a way to turn off telnet line mode, but that's not working for me, and/or I don't understand it.

```
write(s,"\377\375\042\377\373\001",6);
```

From what I have found on a forum there might be a way to do it with ncurses.

What is the best way to do it?

what I'm at

```
 12 void doprocessing (int sock)
 13 {   
 14     int n;
 15     int i;
 16     char buffer;
 17     n = recv(sock,&buffer,1,0);
 18     if (n < 0)
 19     {   
 20         perror("ERROR reading from socket");
 21         exit(1);
 22     }
 23     printf("MSG: %c\n",buffer);
 24     n = write(sock,"MSG SENT\n",18);
 25 }
```

Comment: If you put the complete code, will make easier to answer.

Comment: If you only want to read/recv 1 char at a time, why are you asking for 255 of them?

Comment: just as an exemple of what I can do with read(). It's always reading buffer, even when I set it to 1 char, and then I can process it.

Comment: The line-buffering by the peer is surely responsible for the blocking up of comms into lines.  Read the RFC:
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854

Comment: Hmm i used netcat and netcat -t, same result, anyways getting into reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `read()` accepts only `char *.`

`char *` and `char[]` are mostly equivalent in C, certainly for this purpose. Clearly you didn't even try it.

> `recv()` is better but you still need to pass '\n' to get it.

No, `recv()` is identical to `read()` for sockets unless the fourth argument is non-zero, and you don't need to pass `\n` to get it.

> I found a way to turn off telnet line mode, but that's not working for me, and/or I don't understand it.

```
write(s,"\377\375\042\377\373\001",6);
```

This is `IAC DO LINEMODE` (255 253 36), which shouldn't be sent at all by a client, followed by `IAC WILL ECHO` (255 251 1). The correct command is `IAC WILL LINEMODE` (255 251 36) or "\377\373\042", and there will be a reply IAC DO LINEMODE (255 253 36 or `"\377\375\042"`) which is `IAC DO LINEMODE` where the server gives you permission to begin negotiation of the linemode. I suggest you study [RFC1116](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1116) for further details, it is rather complicated, and needs to be read in conjunction with [RFC854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) and others.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right, they are just the same.

Howewer, what I ment was that data is not sent before i hit enter key.

client:
    message
server:
    MSG: m

Comment: That has nothing to do with the network.. that has to do with how you are capturing data that you want to send to the network.

Comment: I know. I'm pointing that what i need is something similar to while(c = getchar()) approach.

Comment: Well if the server doesn't send it you can't receive it. There's nothing wrong with the code you're using. I would persist with turning line-mode off.